# Strange behaviour when instantiating new objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object

I'm a beginner at Python (started around a month ago as a hobby) and I recently began working on a 4D+ modelling/visualization program (however pointless it may sound, it seemed like a fun thing to do). Hence, I started working on some very basic classes/objects and I almost instantly ran into a problem when it came to defining a hypercube procedurally :

### **Main program**

```
import itertools as itt
import numpy as np
import Vertex as vx

def main():
    defineHypercube(4)

def defineHypercube(n=4): #Creates an n-dimensional generalization of the cube
    vertices = [] #List of the hypercube's vertices
    coordList = list(itt.product([0, 1], repeat=n)) #Lists all the possible combinations with n bits (you probably already know though)
    vertexCoords = [] #This list is here because it seemed like the easiest way to go about attributing coordinates to the vertices

    for i in range(2**n): #An n-dimensional hypercube has 2^n vertices
        for coords in range(n): #Each vertex is defined by n coordinates
            vertexCoords.append(coordList[coords*n]) #Gets the x,y,z,w... coordinates for the new vertex

        vertices.append(vx.Vertex(vertexCoords)) #Supposedly adds a new vertex with the coordinates from vertexCoords
        vertexCoords.clear() #Well... it clears the list
        print(list(vertices[i].coords)) #Used to check if I got it right
main()
```

### **Vertex class**

```
import numpy as np

class Vertex:
    coords = []
    def __init__(self, coords):
        self.coords = coords

    """def project():""" #This is here to remind me to get it done soon :')
```

So that's good and all and I can't seem to see what could go wrong, but the thing is I still get this output unexpected output that seems to indicate that there was a problem during the whole coordinates assignment process :

[image: output]

O masters of python, please lend a hand to this puny beginner that's been stuck for a full day on this issue :v

Comment: Assignment does not make a copy of the list like it would in C/C++. So you are using the same list for every object instance, and clearing it when all is said and done.

Comment: What you're passing to the new objects is a pointer to the `vertexCoords` list. This list is shared among all of them.

Comment: Ooooooh that makes a lot of sense now that I think about it... how would I go about giving one list's values to the other one ?

Comment: Create `vertexCoords` in the `2**n` loop, and don't clear it.

Comment: Or, alternatively, and probably more robustly, make a copy of the list in `__init__`: `self.coords = list(coords)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a new list to the Vertex each time. A quick way to generate one is with a list comprehension.

```
vertexCoords = [coordList[coords*n] for coords in range(n)]
vertices.append(vx.Vertex(vertexCoords))
```

Note, you don't need (and shouldn't have) that class-level `coords` declaration; it is shadowed by the instance variable defined in `__init__`.

Comment: You could just use a slice with a step: `vertexCoords = coordList[::n]`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, ensure that you assign a new list to `vertexCoords` as many times as you need a fresh list. Your attempt to reuse one list again and again is what caused your bug.

```
for i in range(2**n): 
    vertexCoords = []
    for coords in range(n): 
        vertexCoords.append(coordList[coords*n])
    vertices.append(vx.Vertex(vertexCoords))
```

Don't clear any lists. The assignment statement on the second line will associate `vertexCoords` with a new list on every loop iteration, breaking the reference to the old list. The old list is not lost, since you've passed a reference to `vx.Vertex()` which is now stored in the `coords` attribute.